# CKEditor: Allow content in nested widget, which isn't allowed in parent

Tags: widget, ckeditor

I'd like to know if it is possible to allow content in a nested widget which isn't allowed by the parent widget.

I tried to allow images in the nested widget (using "img[alt,!src];"). The parent doesn't allow images. I can place images in the inner widget but it's filtered afterwards (e.g. by switching to source code and back).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I remember this will not be possible. The whole content is first passed through the main filter, and then each of editables passes its content through its filter. Unfortunately, implementing widgets in CKEditor 4.3 (meaning - dozens of major relases since 3.0) we had many architecture limitations and this was one of them.

You can, however:

- mark elements which should not be filtered with `data-cke-filter="off"` attributes, but this solution is pretty inconvenient, because all `data-cke-*` attributes are automatically removed when getting data from editor, so you would need to add it dynamically when loading data,
- use [`editor.filter.addElementCallback()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-addElementCallback) - with this you can disable filtering of a chosen subtrees. You will need to check context of the element that you're skipping, to allow these images only inside future widgets, but not outside them.